# Balls collision

Tags: combinatorics

Two sets of subsequent balls are sliding along a straight line: 147 from left to right and 173 from right to left. Their speeds are of equal value but different directions (left – right). At some given moment, the two sets approach and start to collide with each other in an elastic collision. How many collisions will take place in total and between which two balls will the last collision take place?

I assume that once they collide, they change direction but not speed.
So once the two sets approach, number L147 will collide with number R173 so R173 will join the left set and L147 the right. Then R173 will collide with R172 and L147 with L146. I can't clearly see any pattern.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: 
Assuming equal masses and conservation of momentum, two balls colliding with each other (and each reversing direction) is equivalent to the two balls passing through each other and continuing in the same direction.

[Here, equivalent in the sense that you still have a ball moving to the left and a ball moving to the right from the collision point.]

Answer (score 3):

HINT

From a conservation of momentum point of view: after all the collisions are done, how many balls should be moving to the left, and how many to the right?

In this case, you basically have a 'mass' of 147 units moving from left to right, and one of 173 units from right to left (I am assuming all balls have the same mass and speed) i.e. you have an 'excess' of momentum going from right to left. By the conservation of momentum principle that excess should still exist after the collision, i.e after the collision you should *still* have 147 balls moving to the right, and 173 balls moving to the left. From that fact you can quickly infer which the last two balls were that collided: The 147 balls moving to the right after all the collisions must be balls $R1$ through $R147$, and thus all of the balls $L1$ through $L147$ together with $R148$ through $R173$ now move to the left, and that means that the last collision was between $R147$ and $R148$.

From there you can now solve the rest of the problem.

Comment: I assume that after the collisions, there must be 147 balls to the left and 173 to the right.

Comment: No.  Think about the mass (we are assuming all balls have equal mass .. and are traveling with equal speed): suppose you had big heavy ball colliding with a light ball ... then you know just form experience that the heavy ball is not going to suddenly move back in the other direction ... it will probably keep moving in the same direction, just with a little less speed.  That is, there is more momentum going in the direction of the heavy ball, and after the collision that should still be true. This intuition is compatible with the conservation of momentum principle in physics. ..(continued)

Comment: In this case, you basically have a 'mass' of 147 units moving from left to right, and one of 173 from right to left, i.e. you have an 'excess' of momentum going from right to left, and after the collision that should still be true, so after the collision you should still have 147 balls moving to the right, and 173 balls moving to the left. So from that fact you can quickly infer which the last two balls were that collided, and from there solve the rest of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

To do it the hard way, the outer $147$ balls on each side turn around, so must each have an odd number of impacts, one more from the center than from the outside.  The inner $26$ balls on the left continue through, so each have an even number of impacts.  The outer ball on each side gets just one impact.  The next one in gets one hit from outside, so two from the inside, for a total of three.  The next supplies those two hits from the inside, so needs three from its inside for a total of five.  The total for all $147$ outside balls on the left is $1+3+5+\ldots +2\cdot 147-1=147^2.$  The $147$ balls on the right also account for $147^2$ impacts.  The leftmost ball of the center $26$ supplies the $147$ impacts from the center that its left hand neighbor got and must get $147$ more from the right, so each center ball gets $2 \cdot 147$ impacts.  We have counted impacts on each ball, which are twice the number of collisions, so need to divide by $2$. The grand total is then $ 147^2 + 26 \cdot 147=25431$

Comment: Did you double count?  Two balls colliding should only count as one collision.

Comment: @paw88789:  yes, you are right.  Thanks

Comment: @RossMillikan: Wow! Great solution! So finally which are the last two balls that collide?

Comment: @CarlosLopez:  paw88789:'s simple model answers that, too.  They are the last ones that exit in each direction, so it would be the 147th and 148th that enter from the right.  That collision sends the 147th to the right and the 148th to the left.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different way of looking at and answering the question of how many collisions you are going to get.

Imagine that instead of colliding, the two balls simply go through each other.  Aside from a moment during which the two balls take up the same space, the end effect is exactly the same as when they do collide: beforehand, one ball goes to the right and the other one goes to the right, and afterwards we still have that one ball goes to the right and the other one goes to the right; the difference is simply in terms of which ball it is, but for the overall effect in terms of how many balls go to the right or left there is no difference between these two scenarios. Indeed, from a distance, the pattern of movement will look exactly the same.

However, if we think about the balls going through each other, how many balls are going through each other?  That is of course simply $147\cdot173=25431$, and so that then is also the total number of collisions you end up with in the original scenario.